# React: How to use same component twice in same page but loading one script tag for both just one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a react component that I want to use twice(or more) inside my page, and I need to load a script tag for it inside the head of my page but just once! I mean even if I use the component twice or more in the page it should add the script tag just once in the head. 
The Problem is that this script tag should be absolutely a part of the component and not statically inserted in the head of my page.

Can anyone help me to make the magic happens? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want to do? Do you have a minimal example of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll write a small example right now

Comment: ...

    loadScriptInHead() {
        let script= document.createElement('script');
        script.type= 'text/javascript';
        script.src=  'https://widget.thelink.com/headScript.js';
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }

    renderSave() {

 this.loadScriptInHead();

        return (
            <div>
                <a className="widget"
                data-theme="light"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
...

Comment: So the loadScriptHead function muss be called just one time even if I use the component twice in my page

Comment: Can you just use the dom to check whether you've already loaded the script? I'd also suggest to avoid making side effects in a render method and put it in componentWillMount instead

Comment: @tariklp Is your problem solved? Is there any solution other than `react-helmet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) a try for managing changes to your `<head>` from within React components.

In particular, you can check [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m1z77w029) where rendering the same element four times only adds the script tag once.

For completeness, the relevant code from the example (although the interesting part is to see how it executes):

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

function ComponentWithHeader() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Oh hi</div>
      <Helmet>
        <script src="fake-url.js" />
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ComponentWithHeader />
    <ComponentWithHeader />
    <ComponentWithHeader />
    <ComponentWithHeader />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the state of the parent component to keep in memory that the script is already added.

```
if (!this.state.scriptAdded) {
   // Add script tag
   this.setState({ scriptAdded: true });
}
```